# How to prevent nested node_modules inside node_modules

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-modules

I've created my own npm package, let's call it XYZ, it has `@material-ui` dependency in it's `package.json` file.

When I install it in project A I have nested node_modules inside of XYZ folder(so it's `A\node_modules\XYZ\node_modules\@material-ui`), but when I install it in project B I don't have nested node_modules folder. Both project A and B has `@material-ui` in their `package.json` files with same versions.

How to force my XYZ package to use `@material-ui` from `A\node_modules`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are upside of having less nested folders and downside having more folders in node_modules folder directly and version control problems.

### Use correct npm version

Correct `yarn` and `npm` (ie: npm v3) should not have such structure issue. It should always flatten the whole structure where possible and **only have nested node_modules if the versions are incompatible with the one at top.**

## Check versions

So if you have it working properly on one project and not on another, its probably due to version. Check out if the `@material-ui` is same version on both. Maybe two different packages are conflicting with each other at some point.

## Check how you are installing them

From your question, it says it's same version. However, you did not mention how you installed your package on both project. If you install with `yarn link` or `npm link` it should install dependencies properly as expected.

## Check if you are using different packages

If you check the package, recently `material-ui` has been deprecated, and the notice says to upgrade to `@material-ui/core` instead. It might be some packages inside that folder is not same. Either way, it's like this whenever there is some dependency conflict. Check inside the `@material-ui` folder.

## Flatten them manually (dangerous)

There are several packages to forcefully resolve this issue. They will go thru the nested node_modules folders and flatten them into single folder.

### `flatten-packages`

- Install with, `npm install -g flatten-packages`.
- Run executable `flatten-packages` to rearrange all packages in node_modules folder in the project directory.
- Flatten will delete older version of a package. You should take care of version breaking changes related errors.

Comment: Thank you for explenation. I will double check on monday and accept if it solves my issue

Comment: Reply what worked and what didn't so we can figure out what happened. :)

Comment: It looks like i had the same version of @material-ui/core, but @material-ui/icons were different and that's why I had nested node_modules. Thank you!

Comment: Why not use `npm dedupe` (not dangerous) to flatten the dependency tree?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `npm dedupe` command to accomplish this.

You can put the command in `postinstall` script in `package.json`, and every time NPM installs package, the `npm dedupe` command will flatten all the duplicated packages in same version for you.

For more information, see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe

[npm postinstall script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSSkd.png)

Comment: This is working fine for One level nested dependencies. For following scenario its not working -- `node_modules/dependency1/node_moduels/dependency2/node_modules/dependency_not_being_removed` any suggestions on how to remove in this level

Answer (score 1):

I have another addition to the accepted answer:

### Clear Local node_modules folder Cache

`rm -rf node_modules`

**Handle with care:** Sometimes migrating projects to new npm modules can cause weird cache issues inside a `node_modules` folder, especially those that have been around for a while, or happened to have **newer versions of packages installed in sub-dependencies** that differed from the installed version in root.

Once you remove direct dependencies via the package.json dependencies, the packages will be removed from the `<root>/node_modules`. This can cause a bug where the new modules are still nested under your dependency instead of being moved to root as expected.

So by **wiping out your local node_modules**, you can do a clean reinstall and let the flattening to its work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a React Native app with my NPM package. 
The problem was that in project A the version of React Native used was (0.59.5) below the version used in my package (0.59.8).
Installing the package in a brand new project (B), of course was using the latest version of React Native in that moment, that was the same of my package (0.59.8).