# Can someone please explain npm dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependency-management

I am not a newbie, but I am still confused with the way npm puts packages in `node_modules`.

So, what I can see is:

1. My project's `dependencies` are installed into `node_modules`. That's as expected.
2. Some other packages are installed into the project's `node_modules` as well, even if those packages are not within my project's `dependencies` or `devDependencies`. Okay, I assume that these are dependencies of my project's dependencies and hence, npm throws just every package to the project's `node_modules`.
3. Now the most obscure part. Of those packages (from paragraph 2 above), some contain their own `node_modules` and packages inside it, but others do not contain `node_modules` and store their dependencies in the project's `node_modules`! The heck?

Why is that inconsistent behavior, why some sub-dependencies have their own `node_modules` and other sub-dependencies just drop their deps in the project's `node_modules`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786739/how-to-prevent-nested-node-modules-inside-node-modules

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#cycles-conflicts-and-folder-parsimony

Comment: Consider if module A depends on a specific version of module B, and module C depends on another version of module B. How would you organize those files?

Comment: @user633183 so your rethorical question implies that if there is a package that is depended upon multiple times but different versions of it are depended upon, then npm creates `node_modules` for each of the versions? Otherwise it drops the package to the common, project's `node_modules`?

Comment: @user633183 well, the question stands - why do some drag their own dependencies, while others just grab whatever the project uses.

Comment: Nurbol, I don't want to over simplify things, but just know that the dependency resolver can't dump all the modules and sub modules into the same folder. The links above should help considerably.

Comment: @user633183 Okay, I of course was going to see those, but just wanted to specify. Thanks!

Comment: It could if the folder name would include the version ...

Comment: @JonasWilms npm authors probably should listen to this genius idea! Indeed it would be much more simple.. Interesting, does this approach exist in some other package management system?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thanks, Yuri, that's exactly what I've missed.