# Why yarn install downloads node_modules for dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have a node projection which has a dependency let's say `depA`. After I run `yarn install` on my project, it downloads all dependencies for `depA` in `node_modules/depA/node_modules` which makes the `node_modules` directory very big. It doesn't download this folder for other dependencies. Is there anything I should look at why it happens on `depA`?

Comment: Generally Yarn/NPM does that if there are conflicts between the versions of transitive dependencies `depA` needs and the versions your other dependencies need.

Comment: I see the `node_modules` directory is pretty big. Does it download all dependencies or just download the conflicts dependencies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent nested node\_modules inside node\_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786739/how-to-prevent-nested-node-modules-inside-node-modules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its how dependencies get installed in node.js, a folder with name node_modules is created and then all dependency mentioned in your `package.json` is fetched from npm server and downloaded.

Now comes the twist, say in your package.json has dependency depA only. but library depA internally is dependent on depSubA, depSubB then these 2 will also get downloaded so that depA can work.

In the previous version of npm (before 5 I guess), there used to be subfolders inside node_modules which had their independent dependencies creating chances of duplicities and huge folder, the latest version now shares these common dependencies.

check for more details https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/folders.html

Comment: Does every dependency under `depA` download its own dependencies? Why only `depA` downloads but not others?

Comment: if depA has a dependency on depSubA it will be downloaded

Comment: Is there a way to stop downloading these nested dependencies?

Comment: No, that is how node dependencies work, DENO is going to answer this problem