# How to guarantee that dependency of dependency will be installed directly below "node_modules"?

Tags: node.js, npm

The package **@yamato-daiwa/style_guides** has below depencencies:

```json
{
  "name": "@yamato-daiwa/style_guides",
  "version": "0.0.14",
  // ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.29.0",
    "eslint": "8.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "9.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue-pug": "0.5.2"
  }
}
```

I don't want to make user of **@yamato-daiwa/style_guides** install these depencies manually - I want "everything out of the box" approach.

Depending on project, "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin", "@typescript-eslint/parser" and other dependecies are being installed directly below "node_modules" or no:

**Directly below exmaple**

[image]

**Deep example**

[image]

Currently, the regularity is not clear for me, but if **"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin"** and other dependencies will not be installed directly below **node_modules**, the ESLint simplty will not work:

[image]

Although I still don't understand the concept of **peerDependencies**, I suppose it does not fit for the implementation of "out of box" approach:

> When a dependency is listed in a package as a peerDependency, **it is
> not automatically installed**. Instead, the code that includes the
> package must include it as its dependency.
>
> https://flaviocopes.com/npm-peer-dependencies/

Answer (score 1):

You might find the checklist mentioned in this answer helpful to debug the issue: [How to prevent nested node_modules inside node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786739/how-to-prevent-nested-node-modules-inside-node-modules)

As mentioned, you will get a nested `node_modules` folder inside your package `@yamato-daiwa` when the versions of `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and `@typescript-eslint/parser` you are using (`5.29.0`) are different from the same modules used in your user's project. You can try deduplicating them using [npm-dedupe](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-dedupe), and if it works you can add it as a post-install script in your package.

Also, check if the issue is fixed by prefixing the eslint plugin and parser versions with a `^`. So, it would be **"^5.29.0"**; this will allow `npm` or `yarn` to automatically fetch the latest version of the dependencies and flatten them to use a single version across the project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `dependencies` are always installed automatically, yes, `peerDependencies` are only installed manually.

But, the actual issue is that you're opening files under `node_modules` while those aren't supposed to be opened.

In order to browse a dependency, clone and open their repository as a separate project, then install all dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. "The actual issue is that you're opening files ..." - I am understanding that I doing somthing wrong, but I did not understand how to reach my goal - do not make the users install "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin" etc. manually. Would you please to explain about this?

Comment: Adding it as one of the `dependencies` of your own project will install it automatically in the `node_modules` directory of your project.

Comment: It is what I want to avoid. "of your project" project means "of your user's project", by other words, user must care about deveopments management (it is not just installation - it also the compatibility management during updating). What I am trying to reach is "Just install @yamato-daiwa/style_guides - and don't case about toher dependencies".

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. `dependencies` are installed when `npm install` is ran.